# Is it possible to invoke a flexipage as a quick action or anyhow?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, action, report-chart, flexipages

I found that we can use different action types

[image]

unfortunately, neither of them is what I need.

Is there a hack or trick to "route" to a flexipage? I need that functionality available in the mobile app - therefore I ask about quick actions, hence they seem to be the only "hook" any Visualforce or Lightning Compo (LC) to a record page in the mobile app.

I'm not happy with using a LC as Action Type, because I want to embed report charts and it does not look like they are available to use in a custom LC.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a lightning component and in an init function of it redirect to a flexi page. Then create a quick action and bind it. You may also need some CSS to hide the popup from a quick action so the user only sees the overlay instead of a popup.

Comment: do you think this will work in the Salesforce Mobile App? In other words: can I use the URL-Pattern of LEX to access Flexipages in the Mobile App, or other URL-Patterns? If it works in the Mobile App, I would like this approach a lot!